# Unable to run function in lxterminal on raspberry pi using python

Tags: python, function, terminal, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am attempting to run a simple program on my Raspberry Pi and have not been able to run the code with the blink() function included. When blink() is removed the function works properly.

In the LXTerminal I type -- sudo python3 test.py

Thanks for your assistance.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)

def blink():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(2,True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(2,False)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you call `blink()` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually call `blink`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2,GPIO.OUT)

def blink():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(2,True)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(2,False)
        time.sleep(1)

blink()
```

If you want to run this `script.py` with LXTerminal, then go to the top of the Window and choose `Open LXTerminal here`. Enter `python script.py`.